# Is is possible to use is_page() with child

Tags: wordpress

Portfolio
-Kitchen
-Bathroom
-Interior

This is one part of my menu and I want to show a menu when I go to portfolio or any page under portfolio. I know I can take their ID and use is_page and get what I want. But the problem is in the future if I add another page it`s gonna mess it up. Because I`ll have to add that pages ID into my code. I don`t want to do it actually my customer doesn`t know how to do it. I thought about using !is_page then adding other pages so any other created page will have this menu but what`s gonna happen if they add another page to their website that is not under portfolio ?

Long story short is there any chance I can say is_page portfolio or child of portfolio show this menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_child-functionality can be delivered by using wp_list_pages and the parameter "child_of" like this:

```
wp_list_pages(array('child_of'=>id_of_page));
```

Here is the Codex page for that function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages